# Why does this mod_rewrite rewrite rule cause a loop?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

*Note: I found lots of similar questions on Stack Overflow, but none of them really helped me to figure out the problem. There could be hundreds of reasons why it caused this loop.*

---

I have a file called `user.php` on `example.com`. I wrote a simple rewrite rule in `.htaccess` which removes the `.php` file extension from the URL.

Everything worked fine, except that I received a 500 error when opening `example.com/user/<anything-here>` in the browser. I actually expected a 404 error.

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php
```

I also got the following error in the log:

> ```
> [...] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable
>       configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit
>       if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
>
> [...] r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar.php
> [...] redirected from r->uri = /user/foobar
> ```

---

I tried reproducing the problem step by step, but without success:

- Conditions:

  - `/user/foobar` → Is not a directory? → True, a directory named `foobar` does not exist, so `foobar` is not a directory
  - `/user/foobar.php` → Is a file? → False, a file named `foobar.php` does not exist, so `foobar.php` is not a file
- Rewrite:

  - No rewrite because the second condition is false; the URL remains the same (`/user/foobar`). The server should return a 404 error. However, I received a 500 error instead.

**What exactly went wrong and what caused the loop and why?**

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That can’t be the problem. The path `/user/foobar` doesn’t contain `.php`, so it can’t be the reason. (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have `MultiViews` turned on in your server config. That may be causing `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` to match `user.php` which is an existing file and making your condition true.

Turn it off using this line at the top:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Option `MultiViews` (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/file` is the URL then Apache will serve `/file.html`.

Also suggest you to replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I included `Options -MultiViews` at the top of the `.htaccess` file, but I still receive the same error. I hard reloaded the page several times too and cleared my cache.

Comment: Check my edited answer with suggested new rule with `[L]` flag.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Why did you replace `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` with `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in the second rewrite rule and add the `[L]` flag? Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: As I wrote `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` is resolving to `user.php` not to `/user/foobar.php` and I believe `[L]` flag you can remove for testing and it will still work.

Comment: The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) says `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` returns the full local filesystem path to the file, not just the filename and the extension.

Comment: Yes that's correct it is resolving into `/full/path/to/user.php` in your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196826/discussion-between-lypyrhythm-and-anubhava).